# Live updates of Python matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

We are working on an application capturing data from the COM port and updating in a plot, the code is given below. When plotting, we discovered that plt.plot makes the code very slow and updates come long time after levels change on the device. But on the other hand, using the ion() and set_data functionality does not work at all, it only does one update. Any ideas on how to proceed with these problems? Thanks advance!!!

```
#arduinodata
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200) # open serial port
L=ser.readline()   
read_ser=ser.read() 
the specified file does not exis

Times=[]
EMG1=[]
EMG2=[]
EMG3=[]
AccX=[]
AccY=[]
AccZ=[]

Max_Size=1000   # Til gemming af Sampling efter de bliver slettet i "plot"

def insert(List,Value):
    try:
        List.append (float(Value))
    except:
        List.append(0.0)

    if len(List) > Max_Size:
        List.pop(0)           # fjerner den fÃ¸rste inputtet
    return(List)

def add_row(L):
   # print(L)
    global Times,EMG1, EMG2, EMG3, AccX, AccY, AccZ
    Values=L.split(",")
    if (len(Values) >= 7 ):
        #print(Values)
        Times=insert(Times,Values[0])
        EMG1=insert (EMG1,Values[1])
        EMG2=insert (EMG2,Values[2])
        EMG3=insert (EMG3,Values[3])
        AccX=insert (AccX,Values[4])
        AccY=insert (AccY,Values[5])
        AccZ=insert (AccZ,Values[6])
   

plt.show()

def makeFig():
   plt.plot (EMG1)


while 1==1 :
    
    L=ser.readline()
    #print(type(L.decode()))
    add_row(L.decode())
    #print(L)
    #print(len(Times))
    #Line.set_data(Times,EMG1)
    #figure.canvas.draw()
    
    #figure.canvas.flush_events()
    #time.sleep(0.1)
    drawnow(makeFig)
    #plt.pause(0.01)
Data.write(L.decode())
    # infinite loop 1 or 1==1


    



 #plot"
```

Comment: your code does not seem to be complete, where is the instantiation of `Data`, for instance? And you are probably better off posting your Arduino code, since it might be slowing things down as well. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961121/maximizing-serial-communication-speed-for-live-plotting-data-from-teensy-3-2-usi/56968543#56968543) might be helpful.

Comment: I posted all the code in the new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963659/matplotlib-live-updates