# Matplotlib live updates

Tags: python, matplotlib

We are trying to read continuously from a serial arduino interface and update a plot. The code is given below, but the plot is updated much too slow in comparison to the events on the reader. We have discovered a lag of a few seconds from making something happen on the port to graph changes... Code given below, should we use another framework?

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200)
L=ser.readline()   
read_ser=ser.read() 
Data = open('dataFile1.txt','a')   
Max_Size=1000  

Times=[]
EMG1=[]
EMG2=[]
EMG3=[]
AccX=[]
AccY=[]
AccZ=[]

Max_Size=1000

def insert(List,Value):
    try:
        List.append (float(Value))
    except:
        List.append(0.0)

    if len(List) > Max_Size:
        List.pop(0)           
    return(List)
    
def add_row(L):
    global Times,EMG1, EMG2, EMG3, AccX, AccY, AccZ
    Values=L.split(",")
    if (len(Values) >= 7 ):
        Times=insert(Times,Values[0])
        EMG1=insert (EMG1,Values[1])
        EMG2=insert (EMG2,Values[2])
        EMG3=insert (EMG3,Values[3])
        AccX=insert (AccX,Values[4])
        AccY=insert (AccY,Values[5])
        AccZ=insert (AccZ,Values[6])
   
plt.show()

def makeFig():
   plt.plot (EMG1)

while 1==1 :
    L=ser.readline()
    add_row(L.decode())
    drawnow(makeFig)
```

Comment: As I said in your other question it's not easy to say what's going on if you don't show the code of the device sending data. From what I know I cannot say for sure if it makes sense to use `ser.redline()`. It might be better to read as much data as possible from the buffer with `ser.read(ser.inWaiting()) ` and then process it to account for each line looking for the end of line character. To stress my point: I can and will write an answer as soon as you elaborate on why you are using `ser.readline()` and what kind of data you are receiving (is it 10 bytes per second or 1000 bytes per hour)

Comment: And if you are unwilling or unable to elaborate or share more code you should be able to fix your problem looking carefully at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961121/maximizing-serial-communication-speed-for-live-plotting-data-from-teensy-3-2-usi/56968543#56968543) I referred to before. In summary: read as much data as possible in one go, use numpy, maybe split the task into two threads, one for reading data and one for plotting...